# Moving between tabs while DialogBox is open

Tags: android, dialog

I have 5 tabs in my application.But I cant move between tabs while dialog box is open in current fragment because dialog box displays over the tab.Please help if anyone has solution.Thanks..My dialog box code is given below:

```
public static final void showDialog(Context context, String title,
            String message) {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.MyDialogTheme);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_description);

        TextView text_Title = (TextView) dialog
                .findViewById(R.id.text_desc_title1);
        TextView text_Desc = (TextView) dialog
                .findViewById(R.id.text_desc_main1);
        Button btn_delete = (Button) dialog
                .findViewById(R.id.button_delete_dialog);
        text_Title.setText(title);
        text_Desc.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        text_Desc.setText(Html.fromHtml(message));

        btn_delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();

    }
```

Comment: As long as the `Dialog` is showed, I don't think you can access the background items.

Comment: Use PopupWindow rather Dialog. Because as popupwindow behaviour you can touch outside and popupwindow will dismiss automatically you touch outside the popup.

Comment: The reason is that now setFocus() property currently relies on alertDialog so, the only way is to change the focus and if you change focus alertDialog will dissapear,,from my thought it's impossible to switch tab when the focus was in alertDialog